# Doubly Lists In C

Tags: c, list

I want to find the 5 cheapest products from all shops with `O(n+m)` (`n`=node length of each shop, `m`=products that are available). I have figured out the algorithm in my head but I can't translate into C. I will post the header file with  the `struct`s. Here's what I want to do:

For each shop, sort its products by their price and then create another product list with the 5 cheapest products of each shop and then `sort()` all of them and print the first 5.

```
struct Shop {
    int sid;
    int type;
    struct Product *products;
    struct Shop *next;
    struct Shop *prev;
};

struct Product {
    int pid;
    int quantity;
    int price;
    struct Product *next;
};
/* Global, pointer to the header node of the circular, double-linked list of shops */
struct Shop *H;

/* Global, array of pointers for the use in event 'Find Cheapest Products' */
struct Product *CheapestProducts[5];
```

EDIT: it just adds the products to newProd (like TMP list)
and prints the products, quantity and price  for each shop . its sorted by price.

```
 struct Shop *shop=H;
    struct Product *prod;
    struct Product *newProd;
    int count=0;;
    if(shop==NULL) return 0;
    while(shop->next!=NULL)
    {
            prod=shop->products;
            //newProd=prod;
            sortPrice(prod);
            while(prod!=NULL)
            {
                    newProd=prod;
                     printf("<%d:%d:%d>\t" ,newProd->pid,newProd->quantity,newProd->price);

                    //newProd=prod;
                    newProd=newProd->next;
                    prod=prod->next;
                    //sortPrice(newProd);
                    //sortPrice(newProd);
                    // printf("<%d:%d:%d>\t" ,newProd->pid,newProd->quantity,newProd->price);

            }
            printf("\n");
            //printf("<%d:%d:%d>\t" ,newProd->pid,newProd->quantity,newProd->price);
            shop=shop->next;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to translate my Algorithm into C. 

I can show my code

Comment: yes, show what you have tried so far

Comment: What makes you think posting your code will cause the question to be deleted?  More likely to get deleted if you don't!